# SSRS - Count content, if Y or 1 then “A” otherwise “B”

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

HAPPY NEW YEAR Everyone!!!

My aim is to write a query to return result ACTIVE OR INACTIVE. 
This is what I have done so far. Does anyone know how to write this query correctly?

```
SELECT COUNT (*) AS Active FROM ADF_Course
WHERE CourseActive=1 OR CourseActive='y'
ELSE IF CourseActive=n
THEN CourseActive IS Inactive
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
case when CourseActive='1' OR CourseActive='y' 
then 'Active' else 'Inactive' end AS Active, count(*)
FROM ADF_Course
group by
case when CourseActive='1' OR CourseActive='y' 
then 'Active' else 'Inactive' end
```

Comment: Thanks Jayvee. I go this error when I tried it. Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'y' to data type int.

Comment: I've just changed it to fix that error and include the count by active/inactive

Comment: HA Ha ha! You are faster. I was trying to tweak it. THANK YOU so much. It works!